# Loop over nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, ngfor

I'm having a hard time trying to loop over an array of nested objects using ng7

this is the data I have:

```
data = { 
    'title1': [
    {
      active: true, 
      id: 1 
    },
  {
      active: true, 
      id: 2 
    },
  {
      active: true, 
      id: 3 
    },
  {
      active: true, 
      id: 4 
    }],
  'title2': [
   {
      active: true, 
      id: 1 
    },
  {
      active: true, 
      id: 2 
    },
  {
      active: true, 
      id: 3 
    },
  {
      active: true, 
      id: 4 
    }]              
}
```

I need to print the titles e.g. 'title1' and the rest of the data should be shown nested, issue is, whenever I go for this approach, everything looks ok:

```
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of data| keyvalue">
        <p>{{ item.key }}</p> 
        <p *ngFor="let children of item.value | keyvalue" >
            {{ children.value.id}}
        </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

But whenever I switch my layout to an input checkbox like this:

```
       <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of data| keyvalue">
            <p>{{ item.key }}</p> 
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="events" *ngFor="let children of item.value | keyvalue" />
                event item {{ children.value.id}}
            </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

I get the following error on the browser's console, and nothing renders:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]  on

> {{ item.key }}

Any idea? I'm sure I'm missing something dumb,

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo while writing down the data, there is it edited

Comment: It wasn't an array originally, but an object changed the first [ ] for curly braces

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 set and bind checkboxes with a ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549122/angular-2-set-and-bind-checkboxes-with-a-ngfor)

Comment: Yes, I saw the change you made to the `data` object, but I don't see any difference between your two code snippets at the bottom. They look identical to me.

Comment: Oh, sorry, haven't slept, I've edited it now.

Comment: @RandyCasburn take a look on both questions, I'm not having issue with the data binding, but instead with the rendering and iteration.

Comment: put your ng-for in the label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `children` reference is not in scope when you reference it because the `event item {{children.value.id}}` string is not contained in the `<input>` element.

Define the loop on your `<label>` instead of your `<input>` element:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of data | keyvalue">
      <p>{{ item.key }}</p> 
      <label *ngFor="let children of item.value | keyvalue">
          <input type="checkbox" name="events" />
          event item {{children.value.id}}
      </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot sir. Also thanks for throwing in the explanation.