# How to uncheck the particular check box in forloop in Angular

Tags: angular

```
<div id="collapsefive">
  <ul class="listing-jobs">
    <li *ngFor="let jobData of companyFilter | filter:searchText">
      <span class="radio">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="jobData.compnyname" [checked]="check(checkFilterComp,jobData.compnyname)"
            (click)="searchByFilter(jobData.compnyname,$event,'compnyname')" />
          {{jobData.compnyname}}</label>
      </span>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Ts file

```
clearFilter(fieldNm) {
  if (fieldNm == 'compnyname') {
        ** $('#collapsefive').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked');**

      this.searchText = '';
    $('#compnynameClear').hide();
    $('#compnynameClearDot').hide();
    this.multiCompanyFilter = [];
  }
}
```

In ts file I remove the checked but it's not working.

Comment: Dora, Angular is based in make relations between model (variables in .ts) and view (the .html). Use ngModel or reactive forms. Using jQuery really it's not the "Angular way", see the docs: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use jQuery way then, you can use either of

```
$('#collapsefive').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').prop('checked', false);
```

OR

```
$('#collapsefive').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').attr('checked', false);
```

But, as your checkboxes are dynamic and being checked/unchecked on basis of `check(checkFilterComp,jobData.compnyname)`

You need to have a flag to stop the execution of this method in case of `clear filter` OR in a best manner just change the values accordingly in your list itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the angular way of handling the checked state.

```
$('#collapsefive').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
```

Try using form elements provide by angular.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41307884/1418760